# Laravel setting cookie in middleware so it's available on the same request

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel middleware which sets a cookie if it doesn't exist already:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->cookie('cart_id')) {
            return $next($request)->withCookie(cookie()->forever('cart_id', $this->generateUniqueCartId()));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Simple! The issue is if I try to access that cookie from a Controller on the same request, it returns `null`

```
$request->cookie('cart_id')
```

It's only on subsequent requests that the request contains the cookie.

I understand that the original request never contained the cookie so it makes sense that it returns `null` but I'm wondering if there's a **clean** way of accessing it or will I have to flash it into the session to access it later in that request?

Comment: As far as I know, Middleware is not part of the session life cycle and thus you can't set a cookie in Middleware. I don't have any references to this so correct me if I'm wrong, but I read it somewhere and that might be why?

Comment: The cookie is a part of the session and is only set in the request, so you cannot use it before. Just set the value in a temporary variable

Comment: @Markinson Middleware is part of the session life cycle, the cookie gets set fine, but is only accessable on subsequent requests.

Comment: Ah alright! Was worth a try ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I've solved my issue by creating a class that deals specifically with that cart Cookie generation and making it a singleton class that's injected into the service container.

Once it generates a unique cart id, it will store it so I can access it later in the same request with `app(CartCookie::class)->id()`. If anyone can think of a better way that's still clean then by all means let me know.

Here's the code:

CartCookie.php

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Cart;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CartCookie
{
    private $id;
    private $request;

    function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;

        if ($request->cookie('cart_id')) {
            $this->id = $request->cookie('cart_id');
        } else {
            $this->id = $this->generateUniqueCartId();
        }
    }

    public function id()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    private function generateUniqueCartId()
    {
        do {
            $id = md5(time() . 'cart' . rand(100000000000000, 9999999999999999));
        } while (Cart::find($id));

        return $id;
    }
}
```

CartCookieServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\CartCookie;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CartCookieServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(Request $request)
    {
        $this->app->singleton(CartCookie::class, function ($app) use ($request) {
            return new CartCookie($request);
        });
    }
}
```

CartCookieMiddleware.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Cart;
use Closure;

class CartCookie
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->cookie('cart_id')) {
            $id = app(\App\Services\CartCookie::class)->id();

            return $next($request)->withCookie(cookie()->forever('cart_id', $id));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```